# How I pull the Modified date on a file using .Net similar to this script i found?

Tags: .net, powershell

Here is the script that I have and I have tried finding a substitution for the  System.Diagnostics .Net Code to help me pull a files Modified date....

```
$POSlist = "$PSScriptRoot\POS_BoxServiceList.txt"
#$POSlist = Invoke-Sql2 
$File_Info = @()

foreach ($POS in (Get-Content $POSlist)) 
    {
    IF (Test-Connection $POS -Count 1 -Quiet)
        {
        $Success = $Success + 1
        $Path = "\\"+$POS+"\c$\BoxUploadService\"
        Foreach($File IN (Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "BoxUploadService.exe"))
            {
            $FilePath = $Path+$File
            $ProductVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($FilePath).ProductVersion
            $FileVersion = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($FilePath).FileVersion
            $Info_Properties = [ordered] @{ComputerName=$POS; FileName=$File; ProductVersion=$ProductVersion; FileVersion=$FileVersion}
            $File_Object = New-Object PSObject -Property $Info_Properties
            $File_Info += $File_Object
            }
        }ELSE
            {
            Write-Host "Failed to connect to $POS"
            $Failure = $Failure + 1
            IF (Get-Content $FailureList | Select-String -SimpleMatch "No failures.")
                {
                Remove-Item $FailureList
                New-Item $FailureList
                }
            Add-Content -Path $FailureList -Value $POS
            }
    }
Write-Host $File_Info
$File_Info | Export-Csv $ResultsCsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: If you're to stick to your current method of *concatenating* `$File` to `$Path`, use just the name and not the entirety of the object returned: `$FilePath = $Path + $File.Name`. I personally would use `$FilePath = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $File.Name` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use Get-Item since you already have a fully qualified path with, $FilePath

```
(Get-Item -Path "$FilePath").LastWriteTime
```